# How can I automatically create a document that allows me to compare a list of 4 .png files side-by-side?

Tags: shell, images, html

So I have a list of 4 .png files, and I'd like to auto-pipe this to some document that puts them all side-by-side for easy comparison.

I'm thinking of automatically putting them in a HTML file. So I'd like to use terminal commands to automatically put  for each of the 4 .png files.

How would I best do this via the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hacked together script that will do what you want.

```
$ ( echo -e "<html>\n<body>"; \
    for i in {1..4}.png;do echo "<img src="$i">"; done ; \
    echo -e "</body>\n</html>" ) | tee 4v.html
<html>
<body>
<img src=1.png>
<img src=2.png>
<img src=3.png>
<img src=4.png>
</body>
</html>
```

To display the resulting file, `4v.html`:

```
$ xdg-open 4v.html
```

And the final product:

[image: ss #1]

#### Adjustments

If you want to use a different series of `.png` images merely change the arguments to the `for` loop.

```
for i in {1..4}.png;do echo "<img src="$i">"; done
```

The files are named `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, and `4.png` in my example. So if they were all in a directory by themselves you could do this instead:

```
for i in *.png;do echo "<img src="$i">"; done
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks very much! What if the image names were all contained in an external text file?

Comment: @InquilineKea - if there are no spaces in the file names you can use this: `for i in $(< file.txt); do ....`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ cat > compare.html <<EOF
  html img tags etc
  EOF
```

See [how does `cat << EOF` work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)